# Implement cache using ConcurrentHashMap in Java

Tags: java, caching

How to implement a cache to store 100 elements in memory and implement an LRU algorithm to remove the oldest element if the cache is full.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Caching using ConcurrentHashMap in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43703571/caching-using-concurrenthashmap-in-java)

Answer (score 4):

A Cache is similar to ConcurrentMap, but not quite the same. The most fundamental difference is that a ConcurrentMap persists all elements that are added to it until they are explicitly removed. A Cache, on the other hand, is generally configured to evict entries automatically, in order to constrain its memory footprint.

Since it is a production environment, I would suggest using some existing libraries like [google guava cache](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained) instead of reinventing the wheel.

However, if you wish to design a cache by yourself, several considerations needs to be made like:

1. Max Allowed Size/Max number of elements
2. Population logic
3. Eviction logic
4. Expiration logic
5. Thread safety
6. Memory Leak

The starting point should be defining the functionalities that need to be exposed by the cache via an interface. I'm sure ConcurrentHashMap alone is not sufficient to achieve above-mentioned features. You might need to augment it with other data structures.